# induction machines above 500 hp?

Tags: induction-motor, electric-machine

I have been told in classroom that there are several methods (one-step autotransformer, the star-delta connection and a solid state controler) to start a induction machine above 500 hp, but what I was not told its why the 500 hp limit.

Is this  a rule? Below this level is not necessary these methods? Is this impractical?

Comment: I would be suspicious of any teacher who still uses horse power.

Comment: Believe it, even I was asked in a test this way.

Comment: The question makes no sense, because it leaves out the working machine. E.g. to start a blower, you don't need any special machine or method.

Comment: (I assume this is trade school level and not university. If yes, answer what the courseworks says and clear you mind with a real book afterwards.)

Comment: It might be a practical limitation/rule of thumb - e.g. 500hp is the size at which they typically have too much inertia to start without stalling.

Comment: Again, this is all depending on the type of working machine. E.g. a crane is fundamentally different from a blower from a conveyor from a calender.

Comment: Some electricity supply companies need to know when large plants are to be started to avoid blackouts... and yes, I was there when one company pushed start and the area went down... would love to have heard the phone call ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no universal rule about using reduced-voltage starting methods above a specific power level. The decision is mostly determined by the capacity of the power source. If the motor can be started without causing a problematic voltage sag, it can be started at full voltage. Some power suppliers may prohibit their customers from full-voltage starting of motors above a specific power level. The local power distribution in some industrial facilities may experience a voltage sag if a large motor is started. Another limitation is the construction of the motor. Some manufacturers may not construct larger motors to withstand the stress of full-voltage starting. The important things for a student is to understand the possible limitations and the reduced-voltage starting methods that are available. It may be a good idea to check any proposed motor installation above 500 Hp to make sure the motor can be started at full voltage. It would not be a good idea to assume that every motor larger than 500 Hp needs reduced voltage starting or that smaller motors never need reduced-voltage starting. It is also wrong to believe a motor with any type of load can be started with a reduced-voltage starter.

Answer (score 2):

In North America (because you are using the term Horsepower), the thing that ties to a 500HP limit is that the National Electric Code (US) and Canadian Electric Code limits to the tables where you determine the motor FLA that is used to size conductors and protective devices such as fuses and circuit breakers. Above 500HP, motor design changes can affect the motor current greatly, so the NEC/CEC instructs you to use the actual nameplate FLA. But because of this, many people ASSume that this is a design limit on motors that can be starters Across-The-Line (Direct-On-Line for IEC folks). This is not true. As previously mentioned, whether or not a large motor can be started ATL or requires Reduced Voltage Starting methods varies greatly by location and application. I have seen places where RV starting is required as low as 15HP, I have also started 2,000HP motors ATL. There is no universal rule.

Comment: Ha! Nice and clear, I was thinking the same, that it is impossible (or at least no viable) to set a whole standard or rule to the electrical machines, since the use and design is so different.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not true.

In Ohio, the Siemens Norwood plant offers horizontal AC squirrel-cage induction motors through 18,000 horsepower and voltage ranges from
460 through 13200 volts.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean they can be started direct-on-line. They obviously could, but just because they sell it doesn't necessarily invalidate OP's question.

Comment: Start surges would need appropriate control and may  invalidate limits